# how write Json Web service to fetch coressponding data from from database table in java

Tags: java, mysql, web-services

This is my code :

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import dto.FeedObjects;


public class Project {


    public ArrayList<FeedObjects> GetFeeds(Connection connection) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<FeedObjects> feedData = new ArrayList<FeedObjects>();
        try
        {
            //String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id,title,description,url FROM website ORDER BY id DESC");
            //ps.setString(1,uname);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                FeedObjects feedObject = new FeedObjects();
                feedObject.SetId(rs.getInt("id"));
                feedObject.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
                feedObject.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
                feedObject.setUrl(rs.getString("url"));
                feedData.add(feedObject);
            }
            return feedData;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

This class where are getting data of database table and converting in json format:

```
package webService;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import model.ProjectManager;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import dto.FeedObjects;

@Path("/WebService")
public class FeedService {

    @GET
    @Path("/GetFeeds")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String feed() {
        String feeds = null;
        try {
            ArrayList<FeedObjects> feedData = null;
            ProjectManager projectManager = new ProjectManager();
            feedData = projectManager.GetFeeds();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            feeds = gson.toJson(feedData);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        return feeds;
    }

}
```

package model;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import dao.Database;

import dao.Project;
import dto.FeedObjects;

public class ProjectManager {


public ArrayList<FeedObjects> GetFeeds(String id)throws Exception {
    ArrayList<FeedObjects> feeds = null;
    try {
            Database database= new Database();
            Connection connection = database.Get_Connection();
            Project project= new Project();
            feeds=project.GetFeeds(connection);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return feeds;
}

}
```

There is one more class where we have get set value. i am able to display all database table value in Json format Using this URL But i want when i pass id :

```
http://localhost:8080/RESTfulProject/REST/WebService/GetFeeds?id=1
```

then it should display only id one corresponding name ,title,url. i  have tried using this

http://www.9lessons.info/2012/10/restful-web-services-json-api.html example  but unable to do this plz Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `@QueryParam("id")` `String id` in the `feed` method parameter and get the value of the id and perform your operation based on the value of the id and return the JSON string.Please look below

```
   @GET
    @Path("/GetFeeds")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String feed(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
        String feeds = null;
        try {
            ArrayList<FeedObjects> feedData = null;
            ProjectManager projectManager = new ProjectManager();
            // Modify the GetFeeds method by sending the value of id
            // and prepare feed data based on id
            feedData = projectManager.GetFeeds(id);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            // create the json data for the feed data of the corresponding id value
            feeds = gson.toJson(feedData);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        return feeds;

   }
```

In your GetFeeds method of ProjectManager, the GetFeeds method of Project class is invoked by passing the parameter of Connection type. Modify it to add the parameter of String type to pass the value of id from QueryParam and then modify the query as below

```
SELECT id,title,description,url FROM website where id = 'ID_VALUE_IN_QUERY_PARAM'
```

Hope this clearly explains everything. This will return the only the rows with ID value passed in query string.

Comment: what about feedData = projectManager.GetFeeds(id);  how we can pass while here only one parameter public ArrayList<FeedObjects> GetFeeds(Connection connection) throws Exception

Comment: the code doesn't use GetFeeds from Project class, instead from ProjectManager. you can modify the method GetFeeds with String parameter type 'id' in ProjectManager class

Comment: I have change id But there is not change in value while am calling web service like this http://localhost:8080/RESTfulProject/REST/WebService/GetFeeds?id=4  still all data is coming

Comment: Can you post GetFeeds Method of ProjectManager class? Did you modify the query to add the id in where clause?

Comment: public ArrayList<FeedObjects> GetFeeds(String id)throws Exception {
  ArrayList<FeedObjects> feeds = null;
  try {
       Database database= new Database();
       Connection connection = database.Get_Connection();
    Project project= new Project();
    feeds=project.GetFeeds(connection);
  
  } catch (Exception e) {
   throw e;
  }
  return feeds;
 }

Comment: add the GetFeeds method of ProjectManager class in question itself?

Comment: plz can u send me ur email id  so that i can send complete code plz

Comment: yes thanx now i have to add one more method from that we can get all value of database table which i did before for that we ll have write another method? can u plz tell me about it

Comment: U there plz tell me ur email id i really want to clearfy about webservice plz help me

Comment: Please post your question, i will help you with that

Comment: You can get the email from my profile, but i can help you when time permits. hope you understand.

Comment: NO Problem thanx But plz suggest me i will Implment

Comment: am Unable to find ur email adress

Comment: keerthi_indya@yahoo.com